# Referencing a Tapestry (History)

Tags: citations

I would like to reference The Bayeux Tapestry for a paper. Guidelines state to use "standard footnotes" and doesn't dictate any particular system.

The Tapestry is located in Bayeux, France and the exact date and the creator are not known but thought to be approximately 1070 and commissioned by Bishop Odo of Bayeux.

What would be the most appropriate way to reference such an item?

Comment: Have you visited the tapestry yourself, and are referencing your personal observations about it? Or does your knowledge of this tapestry come from some written (*citable*) source?

Comment: It is based on my personal observations from pictures of the tapestry.

Comment: Then you can reference the source in which the picture is published.

Answer (score 7):

[This website](http://utas.libguides.com/content.php?pid=27520&sid=892673) from the library system at the University of Tasmania provides guidelines for citing works of art in the MLA style. Briefly:

> Citing the original work (you went and saw the Bayeux Tapestry)

Artist (Last, First). *Title of Work*. Date. Medium. Location of the work.

*Bayeux Tapestry*. ca. 1070. Tapestry. Musée de la Tapisserie de Bayeux, Bayeux, France. (Since the artist is unknown, leave this field out.)

> Citing a reproduction of the work (in another source)

Artist. *Title of Work*. Date. Medium. Location (if appropriate). `Source reference.` Plate/page # (if appropriate)

*Bayeux Tapestry*. ca. 1070. Tapestry. Musée de la Tapisserie de Bayeux, Bayeux, France. *Everything You Want to Know About the Bayeux Tapestry*. Ed. B. Ayeux. Bayeux, France: Bayuex Publishers, 2014. Plate 3. Print.

Comment: These patterns seem to derive from (1) treat it like a manuscript, with author, title, date, and home institution; and (2) treat it like a contribution in an edited anthology, with its original information as well as the usual details for a book. This follows the general idea for citing unusual things: adapt the most closely analogous thing you do know how to cite.